# Add new row at end of pandas dataframe with specific value in all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
 Col1     Col2  .....    Col48
 078      abc            0.99
 097      def            0.91
 027      xyz            0.66
 065      90             0.76
```

I want to add new row after the last row with all values '0' in it. So the new df should look like:

```
Col1     Col2  .....    Col48
 078      abc            0.99
 097      def            0.91
 027      xyz            0.66
 065      bcd             0.76
 0         0             0
```

After this, I want to replace the Col2 value from 0 to 'Target so the final dataframe would look like:

```
Col1     Col2  .....    Col48
 078      abc            0.99
 097      def            0.91
 027      xyz            0.66
 065      bcd             0.76
 0        target             0
```

Code:

```
 df.loc[len(df)] = 0
 df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].astype(str)
 df['Col2'].str.replace('0','target')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement), necesary default `RangeIndex`:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = 0
print (df)
   Col1 Col2  Col48
0    78  abc   0.99
1    97  def   0.91
2    27  xyz   0.66
3    65   90   0.76
4     0    0   0.00
```

Another solution is create one column `DataFrame` and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(0, len(df.columns))[None, :], 
                  columns=df.columns,
                  index=[10])

df = pd.concat([df, df1])
print (df)
    Col1 Col2  Col48
0     78  abc   0.99
1     97  def   0.91
2     27  xyz   0.66
3     65   90   0.76
10     0    0   0.00
```

Comment: @Tjs01 - first solution raise error? What is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: I am using this dataframe for generating Logistic regression, that's where it throws this error, I am updating my question

Comment: @Tjd01 so how working `df.loc[len(df)] = [0] + ['target'] + [0] * len(df.columns) - 2`